Return the account name for the most successful creator on the platform, in terms of total income from the AWS dynamodb table
I want to conduct a query to find out account name who has higest income.But i couldnt able to do so in AWS partiQL editor.
the table is like
Account Country Account Name    Account Type    Premium Member  Account Age Total Time Streamed Total Time Watched  Total Income
GB  Miniminter  Creator Y   7   1230    330 988001
GB  Benjy93 Follower    N   5   25  980 1
GB  Becky_P Creator Y   3   220 75  4000
GB  NA_RPGs Creator N   2   120 100 2000
i want to conduct query succesfully what i need to do to do it. As i only need higest income account from the query

DynamoDB doesn't support Aggregate functions. You will have to extract the data out and Sum all or Tally individual incomes to find out.

DynamoDB is an OLTP database, to satisfy your OLAP workload I suggest you streams and Lambda and keeping a table with pre-aggregated values. That will allow you to satisfy your request pattern on an efficient albeit eventually consistent manner.
